# Unix bash complete function + Ruby 2.3

Tags: ruby, bash, unix

I need to make autocomplete for the script.

In bash I can run something like `complete -W 'foo bar baz' my_script` and it will work

But when I try to run this command in ruby, I get `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - complete`

Ruby code may be:

```
`complete -W 'foo bar baz' my_script`
exec "complete -W 'foo bar baz' my_script"
system "complete -W 'foo bar baz' my_script"
```

With open3, open4, IO I've got the same result

Comment: `complete` is a bash built-in; running it from Ruby makes no sense at all.

Comment: A also think so, but I still have this problem and command does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve from this, but since `complete` is a bash feature, you need to run your shell command using bash, i.e. `bash -c complete ...`.

Whether you have to use `system(....)` or backticks, depends on what you want to do with the result. It's unlikely that you really want to a `exec`, though....

Comment: This gives no error, but do nothing. `complete -W 'foo bar' my_script` works, and `bash -c complete -W 'foo bar' my_script` not.

Comment: Your quotes are wrong.  You want `bash -c 'complete -W "foo bar" my_script'` or possibly `bash -c "complete -W 'foo bar' my_script"` if your real value of *foo bar* somehow requires single quotes.